# How can I remove this occurrence in my arraylist instead of just checking if it occurs

Tags: java

The code below if passed set1 = {1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5}  and set2 = {4,5,4} since 4,5,4 occurs consecutively in set1, I want that instead of the following method returning true or false, it removes the consecutive occurrence that is {4, 5, 4} from set1 so set1 = {1,2,5}.

```
public static boolean contains(ArrayList<Integer> set1, ArrayList<Integer> set2) {
OUTER:
for (int i = 0; i < set1.size() - set2.size(); i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++) {
         if (!set1.get(i + j).equals(set2.get(j)))
              continue OUTER;
     return true;
 } 
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I renamed your `contains` to `indexOf` and modified it to use the `List` interface and return an `int` representing the matching index

```
public static int indexOf(List<Integer> set1, List<Integer> set2) {
    OUTER: for (int i = 0; i < set1.size() - set2.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++) {
            if (!set1.get(i + j).equals(set2.get(j)))
                continue OUTER;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then a method to call [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) for all of the matching elements like,

```
public static void removeLinearMatch(List<Integer> al, List<Integer> bl) {
    int size = (bl != null) ? bl.size() : 0;
    int index = indexOf(al, bl);
    while (index > 0 && size > 0) {
        al.remove(index);
        size--;
    }
}
```

Finally to test,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5));
    List<Integer> bl = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 4));
    removeLinearMatch(al, bl);
    System.out.println(al);
}
```

And I get the requested output of

```
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve this by adding another loop:

```
public static boolean remove(ArrayList<Integer> set1, ArrayList<Integer> set2) {
    OUTER: for (int i = 0; i <= set1.size() - set2.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++) {
            if( !set1.get(i + j).equals(set2.get(j))) continue OUTER;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < set2.size(); j++){
            set1.remove(i + set2.size()-1 - j);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Returns *true* if the first set has been modified, *false* if not.

Comment: Thanks I have been able to work my way from your implementation to what I would like for it to do and gave you an up vote for that :)